# Repeat loop until no errors are found

Tags: r

I have a loop that executes a series of operations.

In some cases there is no solution to the problem so the code returns an error.

If I keep re-runing the loop, eventually it finds a solution that executes without error.

I would like to embed the loop into a `while()` statement that repeats the loop until the program does not return any errors or warnings.

I do not want to catch the error. instead I want to repeat trying until there is no error.

How can this be done?

Here is a small example:

```
a<-matrix(NA,ncol=1,nrow=sample(1:5,1))
a[sample(1:5,1),1]<-10
```

here sometimes this can be done sometimes it cannot.
Of course this is a very toy example but the point is that I want to repeat these two lines of code until there is no error.

Comment: You can use `try` to check a condition and if there is no error you set you variable for the while loop to `FALSE`. But some example code might be useful.

Comment: Please post reproducible code and data, and make it clear what you mean by "error."   It's not physically possible for code to work "sometimes" unless you've thrown some randomizer in there

Comment: I added a small reproducible example

Comment: Is my question clear now?

Answer (score 4):

tryCatch is your friend:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  tryCatch({
    print(i)
    if (i==7) stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
  }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
}

[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
ERROR : Urgh, the iphone is in the blender ! 
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

Obviously, you probably want to use a while instead of a for.

Comment: thanks for your help. The error message is given by the program. How do I add that within tryCatch? you have an if (i==7) but in my case it should be 'if error'

Comment: Can you show what kind of error your program is returning?

Comment: I added a toy example above